# Convert fraction to decimal in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to convert 1/2 in python so that when i say print x (where x = 1/2) it returns 0.5

I am looking for the most basic way of doing this, without using any split functions, loops or maps

I have tried float(1/2) but I get 0...
can someone explain me why and how to fix it?

Is it possible to do this without modifying the variable x= 1/2 ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you mean by `without modifying the variable x= 1/2`?

Comment: Is this a trick question as part of a class you're taking?  If so, please mark it as [homework].

Comment: It's also good in Python questions to mark whether you are talking about Python version 2 or 3.

Comment: Since both `Fraction` and `Decimal` are objects in Python's standard library, the question in title implies you want to do this [python - Best way to convert fractions.Fraction to decimal.Decimal? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468697/best-way-to-convert-fractions-fraction-to-decimal-decimal). What this question want to do is to convert a given fraction (as a numerator and a denominator) to a `float` object instead.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In python 3.x any division returns a float;

```
>>> 1/2
0.5
```

To achieve that in python 2.x, you have to force float conversion:

```
>>> 1.0/2
0.5
```

Or to import the division from the "future"

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1/2
0.5
```

**An extra:** there is no built-in fraction type, but there is one in Python's standard library:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> a = Fraction(1, 2) #or Fraction('1/2')
>>> a
Fraction(1, 2)
>>> print a
1/2
>>> float(a)
0.5
```

and so on...

Comment: correction - in Python3, `/` does float division and `//` does int division; where in Python2, depending on the arguments, `/` can be float division (if at least one arg is float) or int (if all args are int)

Comment: @NasBanov Using the term _"int division"_ may be misleading, because it does more than integers, e.g. `0.8 // 0.11` evaluates to `7.0`, The correct term is [floor division](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-floor-division)

Answer (score 11):

If the input is a string,then you could use Fraction directly on the input:

```
from fractions import Fraction

x='1/2'
x=Fraction(x)  #change the type of x from string to Fraction
x=float(x)     #change the type of x from Fraction to float
print x
```

Answer (score 9):

You're probably using Python 2. You can "fix" division by using:

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the start of your script (before any other imports). By default in Python 2, the `/` operator performs integer division when using integer operands, which discards fractional parts of the result.

This has been changed in Python 3 so that `/` is always floating point division. The new `//` operator performs integer division.

Comment: I cant put this inside a function.. its giving me an error saying that the line must be placed at the beginning of the file..

Comment: That's right. Another way to force floating point division is to use at least one floating point operand. So try `1/2.0`, or `1/float(2)`.

Comment: I know that way but the problem is that I cant modify the input.. i cant change x = '1/2'.. all i can do is apply different functions to it in order to get 0.5.. Is it possible that way?

Comment: No. By the time you get the result of `1/2`, it is already zero.

Comment: What "input" are you talking about, exactly? Please explain more about what you are doing.

Comment: @Kartik: The `from __future__ import division` does not go inside the function.  It's the first thing you type when you start running Python.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can force floating point division by specifying a decimal or by multiplying by 1.0. For instance (from inside the python interpreter):

```
>>> print 1/2
0
>>> print 1./2
0.5
>>> x = 1/2
>>> print x
0
>>> x = 1./2
>>> print x
0.5
>>> x = 1.0 * 1/2
>>> print x
0.5
```

EDIT: Looks like I was beaten to the punch in the time it took to type up my response :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no quantity `1/2` anywhere. Python does not represent rational numbers with a built-in type - just integers and floating-point numbers. 1 is divided by 2 - following the integer division rules - resulting in 0. `float(0)` is 0.

Comment: It depends on the version of python.... ow... this is a comment from 2011, so practically no need to downvote this...