# Best way to convert fractions.Fraction to decimal.Decimal?

Tags: python, decimal, standard-library, fractions

In Python, the `fractions.Fraction` and `decimal.Decimal` standard library classes exist to help keep arithmetic with rational numbers precise. For the unfamiliar, an example of where it helps:

```
>>> 1 / 10 * 3
0.30000000000000004
>>> decimal.Decimal('1') / 10 * 3
Decimal('0.3')
>>> fractions.Fraction('1') / 10 * 3
Fraction(3, 10)
```

My question is, if I have a `Fraction`, what's the best way to convert it to a `Decimal`?

Unfortunately the obvious solution doesn't work:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(fractions.Fraction(3, 10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: conversion from Fraction to Decimal is not supported
```

Right now I'm using this code:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(float(fractions.Fraction(3, 10)))
Decimal('0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875')
```

Now, when I actually output this value, any amount of rounding will convert it to 0.3, and I only do this conversion immediately before output (all the core math is done with `Fraction`). Still, it seems a bit silly to me that I can't get a `Decimal('0.3')` from a `Fraction(3, 10)`. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "In Python, the `fractions.Fraction` and `decimal.Decimal` standard library classes exist to help keep arithmetic with rational numbers precise."  Not quite.  `Decimal.decimal` is still floating point, it's just base-10 floating point.  `Decimal(1) / Decimal(3)` cannot give a precise answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about leaving the division of the fraction to `Decimal()` itself?

```
def decimal_from_fraction(frac):
    return frac.numerator / decimal.Decimal(frac.denominator)
```

This is what `Fraction.__float__()` does (simply divide the numerator by the denominator), but by turning at least one of the two values into a `Decimal` object you get to control the output.

This lets you use the `decimal` context:

```
>>> decimal_from_fraction(fractions.Fraction(3, 10))
Decimal('0.3')
>>> decimal_from_fraction(fractions.Fraction(1, 55))
Decimal('0.01818181818181818181818181818')
>>> with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
...    ctx.prec = 4
...    decimal_from_fraction(fractions.Fraction(1, 55))
...
Decimal('0.01818')
```

Comment: Is there a reason that the conversion the other way is supported by a  class method `from_decimal`? `frac = fractions.Fraction.from_decimal(decimal.Decimal('0.3'))` is valid, but there's no `from_fraction` method for `Decimal`.

Comment: @roganjosh: there is no standard hook to convert values is the other direction, while there is for `float()` (in the form of `__float__`). You could file a feature request with the project.

Comment: @roganjosh: ah, [there was a feature request](http://bugs.python.org/issue15136) but that request never reached consensus as to how to best implement this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, well you posted that just as I was about to ask whether you thought such a request would be worthwhile considering you have presented a clean workaround. I was mostly curious as to whether I was missing something fundamental about why the conversion couldn't be done cleanly in the other direction. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite a new answer, as [Martijn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40468867/16436774) is still the best option, but instead a note about how a "proper" conversion method may be on the horizon.

Python 3.12 has introduced [float-style formatting for `Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#fractions), which permits the following rather hacky function:

```py
def decimal_from_fraction(frac):
    return decimal.Decimal(f"{frac:.<prec>f}")     # can also use `.g`
```

where `<prec>` is the desired precision. It must unfortunately be fixed in the function, and to be useful exceed the precision of the global `Decimal` context. Nonethless, the precision can be arbitrarily large.

All of this is to say that the bells and whistles for going straight to a `Decimal` are more than present (up to traps and rounding), and some of the [contested implementation details](http://bugs.python.org/issue15136) have been decided (with frankly little fanfare). Hopefully this story gets a happy ending soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert an `str` step, which produces a "nice" decimal string (likely exact, if you're actually dealing with "decimal numbers" like that 0.3, which you likely are if you're using `decimal`).

```py
import decimal, fractions

print(decimal.Decimal(str(float(fractions.Fraction(3, 10)))))
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3IzJzC_KLShRSUpMzcxNzdBTSihKTSzLz84q5uAqKMvNKNKAyei4QWqO4pEgjLSc_sUQDrlTPDcrSMNZRMDTQBAGI-VBrYNYBAA)):

```
0.3
```