# fractions.Fraction f-strings as float with __format__

Tags: python, string-formatting, fractions

When using a `fraction.Fraction` in an f-string I would expect to be able to format it as a `float`.  However I get a `TypeError`:

```
from fractions import Fraction
f = Fraction(11/10)
f'{f} as float {f:.3f}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Fraction.__format__
```

It would seem that the floating point format specs could/should be supported for `Fractions`.

Interestingly they are for `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
f = Decimal('1.1')
f'{f} as float {f:.3f}'
```

Is there a reason this doesn't work for `Fraction`?

And yes, I know I could do `f'{f} as float {float(f):.3f}'` but I'm asking why that's required.

Comment: `Fraction` doesn't implement a `__format__` method at all, it just has `__str__` and `__repr__`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should not create a fraction like `Fraction(11/10)`. Do `Fraction(11, 10)` instead.

Comment: Note that printing a `Fraction` using `float()` might give the wrong result beyond the 15th significant digit. Using `Decimal` is better.  See [python - Best way to convert fractions.Fraction to decimal.Decimal? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468697/best-way-to-convert-fractions-fraction-to-decimal-decimal)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't implement the `__format__` method in your class, then you automatically get the default formatter, which just applies the str method. consider

```py
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""

    def __str__(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

If i do

```
x = MyClass()
y = f"{x}"
```

then `y` will have the value `"Hello World"` . This is because i get the default formatter, which calls my `__str__`.

I suspect this is the case with the `Fraction` class, because when you do
`help(Fraction.__format__)`
you get

```py
Help on method_descriptor:

__format__(self, format_spec, /)
    Default object formatter.
```

Comment: Yes, I guess my question was more about the design philosophy and decisions for not including this as part of the __format__  function for Fraction.  I've searched for a PEP or mailing list discussion about this and can't find anything.

Also, it's strange that this works for Decimal and help(Decimal.__format__) shows the same thing as help(Fraction.__format__)

Comment: Depending on your level of interest, you could go into the Cpython github and try to contact the contributors.  I would not expect a high yield probability from this approach though.